# Chrome Extension : Adding rows to a table on occurrence of an event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a background script `background.js` that pops up a html page `popup.html` which has a script `time.js`. The `content script` monitors the `onbeforeunload` event upon which the **url** is stored(along with other data). The `time.js` script loads the stored data and puts them in a table.

***background.js***

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:"popup.html"});
```

***popup.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id='Div'></div>
    <table id="dataTable"></table>
    <script src="time.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

***time.js***

```
loadData();
function loadData()
{
  chrome.storage.local.get(["HRS","MINS","SECS","URLS"], 
                           function(result) 
                           {
                             var row = document.createElement('tr');
                             var col1 = document.createElement('td');
                             var col2 = document.createElement('td');
                             row.appendChild(col1);
                             row.appendChild(col2);
                             col1.innerHTML = result.URLS;
                             col2.innerHTML = result.HRS+":"+result.MINS+":"+result.SECS;
                             document.getElementById("dataTable").appendChild(row);
                           });
}
```

However, the `popup.html` is only able to display one row(0th row, I guess) every time I click on the `browser action` icon. I want to append rows to the existing table.
I have seen a few posts that talk about creating and appending new rows, but none of them worked. I even tried to store `RowId` and increment it upon the event which worked fine but `row=table.insertRow(RowId)` gave the same problem.
I want to know why is this happening and the possible solution for it.

**EDIT :** I think the problem maybe due to the fact that the `popup.html` loads every time I click on the `Browser Action` button(resetting the previous table). But, I have included the popup inside the background script and background scripts start running in the background of the browser once the extension is loaded(one instance). So I think `popup.html` should also behave the same way and any paragraph/table_row added to it must remain intact.

PS- I'm new to Chrome Extensions and if I'm missing something here, I'd really like to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. `popup.html` loads every time. It is not possible to 'include it in the background'. What you actually did is just set the url which can be accomplished just as well in `manifest.json`

There is no persistence, you have to store your information somewhere and recreate the whole table every time the popup loads.

Save your information in `localStorage`, `chrome.storage` or a myriad of other persistence engines available.

Comment: I changed my method. I am now doing all calculations in the `background script`. I have dynamically created a table in the `background script` and want that table to be used in my `index.html`(which will be loaded on `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`). How can I do that? I have tried storing the table using `chrome.local.storage` and then access it with a script in `index.html` but its not working !

Comment: This is how I tried to store the whole table. Don't know if we can do that `chrome.storage.local.set({"table_data": table}, function()
      {
       console.log("Table Stored");
      });`

Comment: @HisabIrpat store data, not DOM